# Protrobuf - Error : Timeout while inspecting metadata

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight-5.0, protobuf-net

I am receiving the following exception

"**Timeout while inspecting metadata; this may indicate a deadlock. This can often be avoided by preparing necessary serializers during application initialization, rather than allowing multiple threads to perform the initial metadata inspection; please also see the LockContended event (System.String)**"

when attempting to serialize/deserialize an object using protobuf.net.
I am using the  protobuf.net for Silverlight and WCF service. serialize the result on WCF service and deserialize the same response on client(Silverlight) end.

I have used extension method for that. here is code for that

```
 public static byte[] GetSerializeByteArray<T>( this T entity )
    {
          using ( var stream = new MemoryStream() )
            {
                Serializer.Serialize( stream, entity );
                return stream.ToArray();
            }
    }

  public static T DeserializeByteArray<T>( this byte[] byteArray )
    {
        if ( byteArray == null )
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "byteArray" );
        }
        try
        {
            using ( Stream result = new MemoryStream( byteArray ) )
            {
                return Serializer.Deserialize<T>( result );
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception )
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException( "Invalid Type" );
        }
    }
```

and here is our model class that reside on other project(Portable Class Library) and used on both end client(Silverlight) and server(WCF) end.

```
 [ProtoContract]
public class Class1
{
    [ProtoMember( 1 )]
    public string Name       
 }
```

I do not understand that why this exception occurred again and again! 
Can you please explain it to me, Is this a correct way to use protobuf-net implementation.

Comment: That is odd! That model is trivial - it should resolve instantly. Can you tell me **exactly** which dll version number(s) you are using? And what platform version (full .net / portable class library / etc). Also - does this happen on client and server? Or just one? You shouldn't have to do anything special here. Something curious is afoot! unlikely, but the timeout here is actually configurable - is there any chance you've changed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the code from your question to create a test rig, with a simple button etc - the following works fine:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = new Class1 { Name = "abc" };
        var raw = obj.GetSerializeByteArray();
        var clone = raw.DeserializeByteArray<Class1>();
        ((Button)sender).Content = clone.Name;
    }
```

i.e. the button's text gets set to `"abc"`, the value we serialized and deserialized. For this test I am using the NuGet download (i.e. "Manage NuGet Packages..." on the project), which selected 2.0.0.621, automatically selecting the Silverlight build.

There were no issues encountered. Possibilities:

- are you perhaps using a different dll? Maybe the Portable Class Library (PCL) version? This wouldn't be incorrect, since the PCL version should work on Silverlight - I'm merely trying to find an explanation why I can't repro what you are seeing. It is theoretically possible, for example, that there is a bug in the PCL version *only* that I need to investigate.
- is your actual model very much more complicated? You might look at `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.MetadataTimeoutMilliseconds` - this should default to 5 seconds, which is a very long time in any sane case - it would be interesting to know whether increasing this makes it *work*, or whether perhaps some code has *already* changed this to a much smaller value

I don't know if it *is* the case, but ***if*** the problem is that you have a very complicated model (that perhaps is also loading a large number of external assemblies), then one other option might be to pre-generate a serialization assembly. This means you can move all the reflection analysis, thinking, IL emitting, etc up-front to build-time (rather than run-time), generating a dll that you can reference. This is [described here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/introducing-protobuf-net-precompiler.html), and basically you would simply generate the serialization dll, reference it from your silverligh project, and replace that code with:

```
public static byte[] GetSerializeByteArray<T>(this T entity)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        new MyCustomSerializer().Serialize(stream, entity);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}

public static T DeserializeByteArray<T>(this byte[] byteArray)
{
    if (byteArray == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("byteArray");
    }
    try
    {
        using (Stream result = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {
            return (T)(new MyCustomSerializer().Deserialize(result, null, typeof(T)));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid Type");
    }
}
```

where `MyCustomSerializer` is whatever you called the generated type.